# prismjsで、コードを行ごとに交互色で表示したい

Tags: css

[prismjs](https://prismjs.com/)で、コードを行ごとに交互色で表示したい。

試したこと
・オプションを見たのですが、見つかりませんでした。
・prismjs実行後のhtmlソースコードを見たのですが、(少なくとも見た目上は行単位ではなく)`<code><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></code>`構成になっていました。

Comment: 「行ごとに交互に色付け」はテーブルデータ等に対して行うのがメインであり、ソースコードに適用する例は (個人的に) 見たことがありません。